# Is it possible to fire any event in c# application when the application is terminated from taskmanager's process?

Tags: c#

I have a c# form application. when this form is closed from task-manager's process i have to do something in my Form application. is it possible?

I apologies if i mislead anything. but i need this solution.

Comment: No you can't, what you can do though is do something just before the form is disposed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx. What exactly are you trying to archieve?

Comment: @Marco Actually i have to call a webservice method when it is closed. it is working fine when i close it normally form my application exit button. but when i try to close it from taskmanager's process it do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not. What you can do, in order to *track* this kind of situation, is on startup create some *hidden file* in directory where you guaranteed by the OS for write permit and on the close of your application, delete that file.

In this way, if on startup of your app, you will find *hidden file*, that will mean that application was closed non in normal way. So you can execute some actions accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. it's a good solution. i will accept your answer if i am running a single form application which interacting with web service. real scenery is Each form is using a ClientID which is come from webservice. when a form is closed it need to send a webservice request back to release the clientID that other form can use this clientID later.

Comment: @Rezoan: in "normal" circumstances you do what you say. My solution is for *exceptional* cases, when your process was killed, or crashed. In this case you will communicate to web service on *next* startup. May be also you can think about implementing some timer on servr side, if you don't get any request (say in 24 hour) form the givel client, unload it automatically. Just an idea....

Comment: This is the correct solution because it also works in other cases where the application is shut down incorrectly. For example, if the power cord is ripped out of the wall. Even if you somehow wired up an event to the Task Manager's killing your app (or hooked the ExitProcess API), you'd miss all other ways that an app could be forcibly ripped from memory.

Comment: How about a situation when multiple instances of application running allowed

Comment: You still can manage that via some file, shared mutex. Some resource that every instance is knowledgeable about.

Answer (score 1):

The task manager will try to close your application gracefully first. You will get a normal close signal that you can act on. In a Forms Application that probably corresponds to the OnClose/Closing of the main window. If this signal is not used to end the application in time, the task manager will kill the process. You will not be able to intercept that or act upon it.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that claim? I believe windows will just kill the process if you end the process (from the process tab of process explorer). Unlike Linux it will not send a signal to the process being terminated.

Comment: Correction: if you "kill task" it will send a signal, if you "kill process", it will not.

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for the info. but i have to find a way for "Kill Process"

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I know, Killing a process with Task Manager is immediate.
The application is not able to get informed in any way.

Task manager generally call the Windows API ExitProcess to kill the process.

On how to hook API, you can refer to:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx

[SOURCE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/bc956176-f595-4407-a9b2-4c659966064b)

In alternatve, you could create an additional process which obsverve the main application and if he find that the application is closed then do something. If the main application is closed normally, then the process is killed from the main application. thiS could be an easy workaround.

Comment: The task manager will kill all threads. You would need another *process* to watch over your first process.

Answer (score 1):

"No you can't, what you can do though is do something just before the form is disposed. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/…. What exactly are you trying to archieve? –"

**UPDATE**

Based on your response to my comment:

What if you do something else. Create a windows service (daemon) that checks when your form is open (windows name) and then monitors the form to check when it is closed, and when that happens it calls the web service you need.

Your windows service would be as simple as this:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!formClosed)
            {
                if (!Process.GetProcesses().Any(x => x.MainWindow.Title.Contains(windowName)))
                {
                    //form closed, call your web service
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks. i will doing this and let you know and everybody who has suggested this solution. but it will be better if can do this form my Win Form.

Comment: Like I said before Rezoan, you can't do it the way you want, because when the form is closed in the task manager all threads are destroyed. Let us know if you have other issues.